# error: MainApplication is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, android, react-native

PLEASE HELP!! I have been search all over but getting no answer

**error: MainApplication is not abstract and does not override abstract method**

Environment

```
React Native Navigation version: 7.24.0
React Native version: 0.66.3
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21 // Or higher
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    supportVersion = "28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "16.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVisionVersion = "17.0.2"
    reactNativeVersion = "+"
    kotlinVersion = "1.5.31" // Or any version above 1.3.x
    RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion

  repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
         mavenLocal()
         mavenCentral()
  }



configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
         maven {
             url 'https://maven.google.com/'
             name 'Google'
         }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  }
}

  subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "29.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && !details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                details.useVersion "17.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') && details.requested.name.contains('play-services-stats')) {
                details.useVersion "+"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prasiam.trader"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.4"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google() // Google's Maven repository
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }           
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support' && requested.name != 'multidex') {
            details.useVersion "${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(':react-native-firebase:')) {
        transitive = false
    }

    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.2.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-afs-native:19.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.2"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    
    testImplementation ("org.robolectric:robolectric:4.7.2"){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-model'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-project'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.maven', module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude group: "org.apache.maven.wagon"
}

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My MainApplication

```
import android.app.Application;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.reactnativenavigation.react.NavigationReactNativeHost;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationActivity;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

  @Override
  public String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDebug() {
    // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
  }

  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    // Add additional packages you require here
    // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new RNFirebasePackage(),
      new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
      new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
      new VectorIconsPackage(),
      new RNDeviceInfo()
    );
  }

  @Override
  public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
    return getPackages();
  }
}
```

ERROR:

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> C:\Users\user\Downloads\Scripts\kantongin-mobile\trader\android\app\src\main\java\com\prasiam\trader\MainApplication.java:23: error: MainApplication is not abstr
> act and does not override abstract method getReactNativeHost() in ReactApplication

**public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {**
^
C:\Users\user\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\android\app\src\main\java\com\prasiam\trader\MainApplication.java:25: error: method does not override or
implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
C:\Users\user\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\trader\android\app\src\main\java\com\prasiam\trader\MainApplication.java:30: error: method does not override or
implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
C:\Users\user\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\android\app\src\main\java\com\prasiam\trader\MainApplication.java:48: error: method does not override or
implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
4 errors

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

THANKS in Advance

Comment: the error message tells you exactly what is going on. Have you read it? Your MainApplication class must provide an implementation for the method: getReactNativeHost(). It is that simple

Comment: I am extremely new please show some example i tried adding     private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
            new NavigationReactNativeHost(this) { but not working

Comment: Nice going #runner366...  some folks will always try to make you feel small, but many of us here have learned by taking on huge challenges and figuring out our way through them.  Making people feel small for not knowing stuff is what we call 'gatekeeping' these days, and its ugly and unhelpful. Don't let harsh criticism get you down.  Your question was detailed and well written.  Learning is OK!  @Stultuske could do to reflect on their tone and tact.

Comment: it's ok  got the app build successfully but it crashes. This app is NOT done by me i just want to test the app

Comment: @TimOgilvy yes, the question is detailed and well written. It also contains the answer to the question, that's the issue. In order to solve his problem, he needs to make sure that the MainApplication class contains an implementation for the getReactNativeHost() method, just as I stated in my first comment. Yes, it is in fact, that simple.
adding a method is about the most simple thing one can do. If this goes over your head, it's no use trying to build more complex apps. This has nothing to do with tact, but with common sense

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this now, you just need to add an implementation of the getReactNativeHost() method. I ran into this problem because I missed it when I was upgrading react native.

Refer to the MainApplication.java to double check your changes/files (make sure to change the versions to match your project):
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.3&to=0.69.3